# How to install libpq on Heroku?

Tags: r, postgresql, heroku

So, I've been able to deploy a Heroku APP that is supposed to contain my RScripts: `init.R` and `access_heroku.R`

My main objective is to test how to save and access a database on Heroku, in order to query it and make some plots (most probably in a ShinyApp in the future).

So, I've also found this gist by the talented: @hrbrmstr

https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/45c67103a9728f59212cd13262adca74

And this other tutorial on how to install packages in Heroku via an `init.R` script.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/running-an-r-script-on-heroku/

**init.R**

```html
my_packages <- c("processx","RPostgres","httr", "dbplyr", "tidyverse")
install_if_missing <- function(p) {
  if(p %in% rownames(installed.packages())==FALSE){
    install.packages(p)}
}

invisible(sapply(my_packages, install_if_missing))
```

Unfortunatly, when deploying to heroku I get this error saying that `libpq` was not found and therefor `RPostgres` could not be installed.

Heroku-APP URL: https://blooming-waters-73325.herokuapp.com/

```
remote:        * installing *source* package ‘RPostgres’ ...
    remote:        ** package ‘RPostgres’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    remote:        Using PKG_CFLAGS=
    remote:        Using PKG_LIBS=-lpq
    remote:        ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
    remote:        Configuration failed because libpq was not found
```

As you can see below, it gives you instructions on how to install `libpq` on different systems. I don't know in which "system" my heroku app is deployed so I don't know what option to implement and how?

Should I put it in `init.R`?

```
remote: -----> R Console app detected
remote: -----> Vendoring R 3.4.4 for heroku-16 stack (latest)
remote:        Retrieving R binaries from cache
remote: -----> Executing R init script
remote:        Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
remote:        (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
remote:        trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/RPostgres_1.1.1.tar.gz'
remote:        Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 44803 bytes (43 KB)
remote:        ==================================================
remote:        downloaded 43 KB
remote:
remote:        * installing *source* package ‘RPostgres’ ...
remote:        ** package ‘RPostgres’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
remote:        Using PKG_CFLAGS=
remote:        Using PKG_LIBS=-lpq
remote:        ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
remote:        Configuration failed because libpq was not found. Try installing:
remote:         * deb: libpq-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
remote:         * rpm: postgresql-devel (Fedora, EPEL)
remote:         * rpm: postgreql8-devel, psstgresql92-devel, postgresql93-devel, or postgresql94-devel (Am
azon Linux)
remote:         * csw: postgresql_dev (Solaris)
remote:         * brew: libpq (OSX)
remote:        If libpq is already installed, check that either:
remote:        (i)  'pkg-config' is in your PATH AND PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains
remote:             a libpq.pc file; or
remote:        (ii) 'pg_config' is in your PATH.
remote:        If neither can detect , you can set INCLUDE_DIR
remote:        and LIB_DIR manually via:
remote:        R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
remote:        --------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RPostgres’
remote:        * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RPostgres’
remote:
remote:        The downloaded source packages are in
remote:         ‘/tmp/RtmpZjXuPF/downloaded_packages’
remote:        Warning message:
remote:        In install.packages(p) :
remote:          installation of package ‘RPostgres’ had non-zero exit status
remote:        R 3.4.4 successfully installed (with init)
```

At the end, I'd like to host the iris data set on Heroku and have the possibility to query it to show some plots. My script only prints it at the end but that is ok, as I know how to make plots with `ggplot2`.

**UPDATE 1:**

Thanks to Chris's answer I was able to install `libpq-dev`,  but now I'm getting this error:

```
remote:        Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
    remote:        Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
    remote:        /usr/bin/mandb: error while loading shared libraries: libmandb-2.7.5.so: cannot open shared
```

So, based on Chris answer I put `libman` on `Aptfile` but now I'm getting:

```
remote: -----> Installing binary dependencies from Aptfile
remote: Reading package lists...
remote: Building dependency tree...
remote: Reading state information...
remote: E: Unable to locate package libmandb-2.7.5
remote: E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libmandb-2.7.5'
remote: E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libmandb-2.7.5'
remote: -----> Executing R init script
```

What can I do?

```
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 371 bytes | 123.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> R Console app detected
remote: -----> Vendoring R 3.4.4 for heroku-16 stack (latest)
remote:        Retrieving R binaries from cache
remote: -----> Installing binary dependencies from Aptfile
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        Reading state information...
remote:        E: Unable to locate package libmandb-2.7.5
remote:        E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libmandb-2.7.5'
remote:        E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libmandb-2.7.5'
remote: -----> Executing R init script
remote:        R 3.4.4 successfully installed (with init)
remote: -----> Caching build outputs
remote:        Build took 68 seconds to complete
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 311.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:  !     Warning: Your slug size exceeds our soft limit (311 MB) which may affect boot time.
remote:        Released v9
remote:        https://blooming-waters-73325.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/blooming-waters-73325.git
   79635e7..4fcab2b  master -> master
```

Comment: This is strange. I don't have a ton of experience with R,  but it is very common to use Postgres from Heroku. Heroku should provide Postgres libraries out of the box. Is R officially supported? Are you using a third-party buildpack? If so, which one?

Comment: @Chris this is the third-party buildpack: https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git#heroku-16 . In my question is the link to the blog post with the steps to upload the app on heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including a file called `Aptfile` in the root of your repository containing

```
libpq-dev
```

This is the name of the Ubuntu package that the error message recommends installing. The R buildpack you're using [should install the package for you](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/tree/heroku-16#installing-binary-dependencies) when you next deploy.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to that part of the Readme. I solved that libpq-dev problem, but now I've other error message. Please, see my update 1. Thanks.

Comment: @OmarGonzales, I was able to deploy a tiny R application with `libpq-dev` to Heroku without any problems using an empty `run.R` and an `Aptfile` containing just the line in this answer. Are you using the `heroku-16` stack? What other libraries are you trying to install? If this is unrelated to the `libpq-dev` installation you should probably ask a new question once you've isolated the cause of this issue.

Comment: the other libraries are in mu init.R file, it is posted in my question, as a hidden snippet. You would need to expand this. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @OmarGonzales, with an empty `run.R`, the `Aptfile` I suggested, and your `init.R`, I was again able to deploy successfully to Heroku. The "libmandb-2.7.5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" message is just a warning, not an error. You don't need to add `libman` in your `Aptfile`. Take it back out, use the `Aptfile` I provided just installing `libpq-dev`, and try out your R code.